# Jenkins error - Remote call on xxxxxxxx failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

```
FATAL: Remote call on Harris MacBook Pro failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:996)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:987)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    at ......remote call to Harris MacBook Pro(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on Harris MacBook Pro failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:838)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:984)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:496)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

I don't understand the issue. Could someone help me? my job is well done but after that I recived this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your Java version, as in [this ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46523):

> Seeing the same thing on Mac OS X High Sierra (10.13.1) running Java 1.9 (build 9_181):

```
$ java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

> This happens whenever the shell is used to execute other processes, such as fastlane to build iOS apps, which in turn calls xcode.
>
> I downgraded Java to 1.8u144 and was able to build.

Java 9 compatibility with Jenkins is followed in [JENKINS-40689](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40689).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue recently.
But in my case, I saw that this was happening only in a specific Slave.
I only rebooted the slave and it was fixed:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Restarting the server worked for me too. Although, I had to restart it from the console.